# Screen Distortion(Black Lines) seen in many Devices

Tags: android

[image]

My Device is connected to PC through USB cable for long time..Later when i go to my application and press on the screen i get black lines as in the Image.I checked my ADB logs

```
08-01 18:11:57.170: I/InputReader(533): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, pending(waiting finished signal)=0, s=0.522 ]
08-01 18:11:57.170: I/InputDispatcher(533): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
08-01 18:11:57.170: I/InputDispatcher(533): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
08-01 18:11:57.170: I/InputDispatcher(533): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
08-01 18:11:57.190: E/memalloc(9818): clean_buffer: ION_IOC_CLEAN_INV_CACHES failed with error - Invalid argument
08-01 18:11:57.190: E/msm8960.gralloc(9818): cannot flush handle 0x83c7c8 (offs=0 len=398000, flags = 0xa8) err=Invalid argument
08-01 18:11:57.240: E/memalloc(9818): clean_buffer: ION_IOC_CLEAN_INV_CACHES failed with error - Invalid argument
08-01 18:11:57.240: E/msm8960.gralloc(9818): cannot flush handle 0x83c7c8 (offs=0 len=398000, flags = 0xa8) err=Invalid argument
08-01 18:11:57.280: E/memalloc(9818): clean_buffer: ION_IOC_CLEAN_INV_CACHES failed with error - Invalid argument
08-01 18:11:57.280: E/msm8960.gralloc(9818): cannot flush handle 0x83c7c8 (offs=0 len=398000, flags = 0xa8) err=Invalid argument
08-01 18:11:57.300: I/InputReader(533): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, pending(waiting finished signal)=1, s=]
08-01 18:11:57.300: I/InputDispatcher(533): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
08-01 18:11:57.300: I/InputDispatcher(533): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
08-01 18:11:57.300: I/InputDispatcher(533): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
08-01 18:11:57.610: I/InputReader(533): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, pending(waiting finished signal)=0, s=0.523 ]
08-01 18:11:57.610: I/InputDispatcher(533): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
08-01 18:11:57.610: I/InputDispatcher(533): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
08-01 18:11:57.610: I/InputDispatcher(533): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
08-01 18:11:57.620: E/memalloc(9818): clean_buffer: ION_IOC_CLEAN_INV_CACHES failed with error - Invalid argument
08-01 18:11:57.620: E/msm8960.gralloc(9818): cannot flush handle 0x83c7c8 (offs=0 len=398000, flags = 0xa8) err=Invalid argument
08-01 18:11:57.670: E/memalloc(9818): clean_buffer: ION_IOC_CLEAN_INV_CACHES failed with error - Invalid argument
08-01 18:11:57.670: E/msm8960.gralloc(9818): cannot flush handle 0x83c7c8 (offs=0 len=398000, flags = 0xa8) err=Invalid argument
08-01 18:11:57.710: E/memalloc(9818): clean_buffer: ION_IOC_CLEAN_INV_CACHES failed with error - Invalid argument
08-01 18:11:57.710: E/msm8960.gralloc(9818): cannot flush handle 0x83c7c8 (offs=0 len=398000, flags = 0xa8) err=Invalid argument
08-01 18:11:57.740: I/InputReader(533): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, pending(waiting finished signal)=0, s=]
08-01 18:11:57.740: I/InputDispatcher(533): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
08-01 18:11:57.740: I/InputDispatcher(533): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
08-01 18:11:57.740: I/InputDispatcher(533): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
```

As in the logs system is trying to do "memalloc" "gralloc"!! Not sure what is wrong!!Please Help

Device Used : Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: Is this just your app or all apps? If it's your whole system, then this site would be a better place for this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: those error messages probably aren't relevant to the drawing bug. Can you describe a bit how you coded up those buttons?

Comment: @Hydrangea yeah will check that!! @ slayton its a TabActivity!! The same issues is not seen in Galaxy S2!!

Comment: And you're saying there's a problem with your code, not your device?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem on the device end. The variable changing here is the device am I correct? The code is the same on both devices (correct me if I am wrong),  so the key is to look for what is different between the S2 and S3 (ie screen density, display, api level). So here is what I would do: try your app out on another phone (maybe your buddy's phone or whatever) and see what happens. Than try to find similarities between the system properties of the phones to try to piece together what is making the error. I hope this helps and good luck! There seems to be something going on with the S3. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936491/android-samsung-galaxy-s3-image-loading) just today. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399851/performance-issue-galaxy-s3) also

Comment: Yes its happening in S3 not in S2!!