# Android - Samsung Galaxy S3 image loading

Tags: android

I have an android app that is working perfectly fine on almost all the Android devices. Recently, I tested this app on Samsung Galaxy S3 and it started crashing on me - it runs out of memory every now and then randomly.

When the app loads up, it loads a splash image and a background image (about 100k in size). When I remove these images from while the app is loading, the app works fine. But when I leave them there, it runs out of memory randomly after the app loads up. I checked the resource directory and the app only has images in the Drawable folder, not in any of the drawable-hdpi or ldpi or mdpi folders. So is the device trying to convert these images to fit the phone's resolution and it's using all the memory? Do we have standard image sizes for hdpi, ldpi and mdpi folders? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason my app failed on Galaxy S3 is because Galaxy S3 has a much higher resolution than any other phones I tested my app with. Hence the memory it allocated for the bitmaps was much higher and that caused the app to crash as it ran out of memory. To solve the issue, I simple removed the bitmaps from the view in the onDestroy method and it solved the issue.